# Help on using NIntegrate Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to take an integral of a super oscillatory function as follows. It takes a long time to solve it with the `NIntegrate` so I added the option `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}`. It's absolutely faster but the answers are completely different.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the options please? Is there any way to take an integral of super oscillatory functions in Mathematica?

In addition, the original integral's results without the option seem kind of weird because they are oscillating between large positive values and large negative values.

I have attached my code:

```
NIntegrate[
  (Exp[(k/(2*Pi))*
    (-a*Abs[r*Cos[t] - rprime*Cos[tprime]] -b*Abs[r*Sin[t] - rprime*Sin[tprime]])])*
      Cos[k*Abs[r*Cos[t]-rprime*Cos[tprime]]]*r*rprime, 
  {r, 0,Infinity}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, {rprime, 0, Infinity}, {tprime, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Comment: Since you are using `NIntegrate`, what are the values for `a`, `b`, and `k`?

Comment: a=3.2, b=7 and k can be a value between 0.1 to infinity, actually I want to compare the results for different value of k.